# Refresh Options Menu after exit from Preference

Tags: android

I have one Item  (and the Icon) in the main menu that depend to one Checkbox in the preference menu.
When I check the Checkbox the Icon appear and are Enabled, otherwise the Icon disappear or are gray and Disabled.
For make that I use :

```
@Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu (Menu menu) {

        boolean isactive = _appSettings.IsSendReportActive();

        menu.findItem(R.id.action_send).setEnabled(isactive);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_send).setVisible(isactive);
        return true;
    }
```

but the menu enabled o disabled only when I select the menu in the MainActivity, I would like after exit from the Preference Menu.
Is Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the activity is created the first time you can setup you menu options in `onCreateOptionsMenu` function.

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

  boolean isactive = _appSettings.IsSendReportActive();

  menu.findItem(R.id.action_send).setEnabled(isactive);
  menu.findItem(R.id.action_send).setVisible(isactive);

  return true;
}
```

When you come back to the activity, you can call `invalidateOptionsMenu()` function in `onResume()` for redrawing the menu. It recall the `onCreateOptionsMenu` function.

```
protected void onResume() {
  super.onResume();
  invalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```